# ListView Item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm working on the design of my app, but I have some problems with the design of ListView's items.

Attacched you can find how it looks like, and how I wanted it to be.

This is the layout for the items:

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        />


        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favourite_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/text1"
            android:src="@drawable/is_not_favourite"
            android:contentDescription="@string/list_favorites_status"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_margin="9dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />



  </TwoLineListItem>
```

The problem is the text: I dont want the description to overflow in the space that should be empty.
Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: How it looks like]

[image: How it should be]

Comment: you are using `wrapContent` instead of giving a value.

Comment: It is just a matter of correctly structuring your layouts. Your layout above, you have got a text view (your title) followed by a relativelayout (your image) this then basically floats off to the right, and then your final textview (your description) which just eats up all the remaining space.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that I want to leave blank the space under the star, and not let the text overflow in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, you can do the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    ....
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    ....>
    <LinearLayout
        ....
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        ....>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a basic layout, you could also achieve the same with RelativeLayout